# как сделать такой слайдер с анимацией

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли такой слайдер сделать через slick, если нет то какой использовать?

Comment: у каждого второго слайда делайте отступ сверху: `:nth-child(2n)`